# ui-router onEnter "TypeError: Cannot read property 'globals' of null"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the `onEnter` property of ui-router state to redirect to a different state depending upon the user-type.

The problem is that it gives `TypeError: Cannot read property 'globals' of null at $state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition` when the 'dashboard' state (the one with the onEnter) is used in a `ui-sref` (the same error is thown if `ng-click` with $state.go('dashboard') is used.

I also created a very simple example, without resolve, showing this problem

[js-fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/klode/v6znebs5/).

Am I missing something?

in template

```
<a href="" ui-sref="dashboard">DASHBOARD</a>
```

in the config

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            resolve: {
                user: function(authService) {
                    return authService.requestUser();
                }
            },
            views: {
                'footer@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/footer.html',
                }
            }
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            parent: 'root',
            url: '/',
            onEnter: ['$state', 'authService', function($state, authService){
                console.log ('redirectTo');
                if (authService.isStudent()) {
                    $state.go('student');
                }
                if (authService.isTeacher()) {
                    $state.go('teacher');
                }
            }]
        })
        .state('student', {
            parent: 'root',
            url: '/student',
            views: {
                'header@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/student/studentHeader.html',
                    controller: 'StudentHeaderCtrl'
                },
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/student/student.html',
                    controller: 'StudentCtrl'
                },
            },
        })
```

**Answer by Thinley Koblensky**:

The problem is caused by using the onEnter property on the dashboard state together with $state.go() and ui-sref

As a workaround:

1. use $location.path() in the onEnter property function
2. and use `ng-href=“/“` or `$location.path(‘/‘)` to navigate to the ‘dashboard’ state

Comment: Using $state.go() in a state config resolve is most likely causing your problem. I've dealt with that before. On my mobile now but if nobody answers I will give a better explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Calling a $state.go inside an onEnter function causes problem because of some kind of variables not properly set up. Here is the git issue of the same problem.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/326

A solution / hack that they suggest in the post is to try to use $location.path() function.

Comment: yes, that is causing the problems. The solution/hack does not always work. For example I need to redirect to 'dashboard' inside of a $stateChangeError and inside of a $stateChangeStart but neither $state.go('dashboard'); nor $location.path('/') would work in there.

Comment: changing the $state.go to $locatio.path inside the onEnter and changing `ui-sref="dashboard"` to `ng-ref="/"` and `$state.go('dashboard')` to `$location.path('/')` wherever a "go to dashboard" is desired woks for some case but not all, as I described in the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

To Avoid this issue, I have tried with `$timeout` and Bingo. It fixes the issue for me. May be, it is just giving some breathing space to ui-router code flow.

```
onExit:  function($timeout){
           'ngInject';
           $timeout(function(){
             // your code
           });
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Thinley Koblensky's answer above - I find a better workaround is to capture the `$stateChangeStart` event then delegate it to the individual states like so:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $injector) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (!toState.data || !angular.isFunction(toState.data.stateChangeStart)) return;
          $injector.invoke(toState.data.stateChangeStart, null, {
            event: event,
            toState: toState,
            toParams: toParams,
            fromState: fromState,
            fromParams: fromParams
          });
     });
  })
```